# Is there any way to automatically assign a slot for items you buy in bed wars?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-bedwars

In bed wars i want my sword in slot 1 and wool in slot 2, but generally my iron and gold goes into slot 2 so i have to move it manually after buying.  Is there any way i can have wool automatically go into slot 2 when I buy it even if that slot is full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where to find the option

[image: Picture of shop GUI]
As shown on this shop GUI, if you click on the blaze powder in the lower right corner you can change the slot that items go in.

[image: Other picture of shop GUI]

### How to use it

[image: Shop GUI]
Click on the items and put them in the preferred slot in the shop GUI (not inventory) under the black glass.
(lol as you can see I lost a game by doing this)

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly!  =)

Comment: welcome @Millard